# google cloud function schedule

Tags: function, cloud

I am running a google cloud function every 1 minute using cloud scheduler (pub/sub). My question is that if the cloud function takes more than 1 minute to run, is it possible for two function instances run at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is. The documentation says:

Important: Depending on how you design your scheduling logic, a function may be triggered multiple times, with the next instance running while the previous instance is still executing.